# Python syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I checked several duplicate questions, but they are not related to python.

This is my script

```
#/bin/python3
import time

# Get the today date and use it as folder name
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

as soon as I try to use it form the terminal (bash shell), I get the syntax error.

```
./test.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `time.strftime'
./test.py: line 5: `print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))'
```

Looking at the code nothing seems to be wrong, and I'm not getting which one is the problem and if it's related to Python or to Linux (as in other posts seems it can depends from linux too).

Comment: This exact code works just fine for me, maybe it has something to do with some obscure symbol in your file or file encoding?

Comment: I just found it.. the problem was in the first line.. It's missing the ! after the #.

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`, removing the tag on that note.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `!` in the first line, so it's just a comment and the whole thing is being interpreted as a sh script.  It should look like this:

```
#!/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Change first string to something like `#!/usr/bin/python3`

You should use `#!` instead of `#`.